# How to override signal handler of superclass component

Tags: qt, inheritance, qml, handler, qt-quick

I have a base class item something like this:

**Base**.qml:

```
Item {
    Thing {
      id: theThing;

      onMySignal: { console.log("The signal"); }   
     }
}
```

And I'm trying to make a derived item - `Derived.qml`.

How can I override the `onMySignal` handler of `theThing`?   I have tried stuff like this...

**Derived**.qml:

```
Base {
    theThing.onMySignal: { console.log("Do different things with theThing in Derived") }
}
```

but I can't find anything to tell me how to express this syntactically correctly, or whether/how to actually go about it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define the code of the signal handler as a property in superclass and override it in the derived item:

```
Item {
    property var handlerCode: function () { console.log("In Superclass") };

    Thing {
      id: theThing;

      onMySignal: handlerCode() 
     }
}
```

Overriding :

```
Base {
    handlerCode: function () { console.log("In Derived Item!") };
}
```

Comment: Or even without adding a property... Just having a function defined in base, you can just create a new one in derived with the same name to override it... So just do `onSignal: callBackFunction()` in Base and define the simple `callBackFunction()` in both Base and the derived components you want